# React/Styled-Components: Need to hand roll a dropdown with multiple versions that a developer could use by passing a type in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, styled-components

A have a dropdown that I created using styled-components. I now need to refactor it into a react component that populates it's options based on props and also offers different styles that can be used across the app by simply including the dropdown and passing it a type as a prop like `<button type="small">, <button type="large">` etc. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this or any resources I can look into for more information? I included a button element from another project as an example below

`Button Example`

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Button as AntButton } from 'antd'

const Button = ({ children, type = 'default', ...props }) => {
  const StyledButton = buttonTypes[type] || AntButton

  return (
    <StyledButton
      type={type}
      {...props}
    >
      {children}
    </StyledButton>
  )
}

const buttonTypes = {
  success: styled(AntButton)`
    ${({ theme }) => theme.buttonStyles.success}
  `,
  warning: styled(AntButton)`
    ${({ theme }) => theme.buttonStyles.warning}
  `,
  danger: styled(AntButton)`
    ${({ theme }) => theme.buttonStyles.danger}
  `,
  link: styled(AntButton)`
    && {
      background-color: transparent;
      border: none;
      color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.primary};
      display: inline;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      box-shadow: none;

      :after,
      :hover,
      :focus {
        border: none;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    }
  `
}

Button.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.oneOf([
    'default',
    'primary',
    'secondary',
    ...Object.keys(buttonTypes)
  ]),
  children: PropTypes.node
}

Button.defaultProps = {
  children: null
}

export default Button
```

`Dropdown (in progress)`

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Dropdown = styled.select`
  padding: 5px 45px 5px 10px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.white};
  border-radius: 0;
  appearance: none;
  background-image: url(${icon});
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 8px center;
`
export default Dropdown
```

Comment: Checkout the [Adapting based on props](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props) section of the styled components documentation. That should help set you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it's best to have one StyledComponent that adapts to the props it's given. Taking an example from the styled-components [documentation](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props):

```
const Button = styled.button`
  /* Adapt the colors based on primary prop */
  background: ${props => props.primary ? "palevioletred" : "white"};
  color: ${props => props.primary ? "white" : "palevioletred"};

  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  border-radius: 3px;
`;
```

Not really knowing exactly what kind of styling you're going after, here's a simple example based on the dropdown you have in your question.

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'

const Dropdown = styled.select`
    padding: 5px 45px 5px 10px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    line-height: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 36px;
    border-radius: 0;
    appearance: none;
    background-image: url(${icon});
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right 8px center;

    ${({ theme, type }) => {
        switch(type) {
            case 'light': 
                return css`
                    background-color: ${theme.colors.white};
                    color: ${theme.colors.darkGrey};
                `;
            case 'dark':
                return css`
                    background-color: ${theme.colors.darkGrey};
                    color: ${theme.colors.white};
                `
            case default:
                return css`
                    background-color: transparent;
                    color: ${theme.colors.darkGrey};
                `
        }

    }}
`;

export default Dropdown;
```

Comment: Awesome, how could I apply this to a dropdown? I added the code for the dropdown that I'm currently working on for context/clarity/

Comment: I updated my answer to use your dropdown instead of the example button. If this answer works for you, please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark in the upper left of my answer, just under the upvote/downvote buttons :)

Comment: Will do! How would I edit what you created for dropdown to include styles for size of dropdown? Like small, medium, large width with font sizes that match?